# yes,i have searched a lot on internet.I could not find answer

Tags: excel

I want to find particular values in sheet 1 that match with sheet 2 and turn that cells to yellow.I want to find errors in this code.

this is table 1

[image]

table2

[image]

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit
Sub match1()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet

    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    If wsSource("A2") = wsTarget("A1:B5") Then
        wsSource("A2").Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If

    If wsSource("A3") = wsTarget("A1:B5") Then
        wsSource("A3").Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If

    If wsSource("A4") = wsTarget("A1:B5") Then
        wsSource("A4").Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If

    If wsSource("A5") = wsTarget("A1:B5") Then
        wsSource("A5").Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If

    If wsSource("B2") = wsTarget("A1:B5") Then
        wsSource("B2").Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If

    If wsSource("B3") = wsTarget("A1:B5") Then
        wsSource("B3").Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If

    If wsSource("B4") = wsTarget("A1:B5") Then
        wsSource("B4").Interior.Color = vbYellow

    End If

    If wsSource("B5") = wsTarget("A1:B5") Then
        wsSource("B5").Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If  
End Sub
```

Comment: help me in my code plz.

Comment: Please read [ask]. And please set a proper title.

Comment: And why don't you use conditional formatting?

Answer (score 0):

All ,of the code lines like this,

```
If wsSource("A2") = wsTarget("A1:B5") Then
```

... should be like this,

```
If application.countif(wsTarget.range("A1:B5"), wsSource.range("A2")) Then
```

In fact, a conditional formatting rule could be based on this same method.

```
=and(countif('sheet2'!$A$1:$B$5, A1))
```